# Css target just class name starts with and Ends with string

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to create certain standard css code for our company and as branding, I want to start all my class names with my company name- and end all with -Cls

```
<div class="Nam-StdCss-Cls"></div>

<div class="Nam-StdCss-Raduis-Cls"></div>

<div class="Nam-StdCss-Border-Cls"></div>
```

Also I want to allow users to use their custom css as well

```
 <div class="Nam-StdCss-Cls menu"></div>

<div class="menu Nam-StdCss-Cls"></div>
```

I tried to do and This is not allowing to enter the custom class like menu.

```
[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-1"][class$="-Cls"]{}
```

I tried and this is not checking starting and ending class name

```
 [class*="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-1"][class$=*-Cls"]{}
```

So I want to know, How we can just check starting and ending **of the class name** and **not the entire string**?

Comment: Without JavaScript you can’t, so far as I know. But I’d be interested to see if that’s changed. Incidentally is JavaScript an acceptable alternative, or do you need it to be pure CSS, even if that’s not possible?

Comment: I would love to get a pure css solution and I wish there should be some tricky way to get this. Some Css developer should have thot about this

Comment: please read tag description before using .. the *class* tag has nothing to do with CSS class (it's written in uppercase)

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question exactly, please let me know if I was able to help you with my answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hungerstar he's aware that his selector isn't working but he want this selector to apply to only one class .. it works fine with one class and he want the same if we add more

Comment: @hungerstar but it's working when we have one class, He simply want this to work if we consider more classes. He basically try to find a more generic case

Comment: @DavidThomas at some degree it can be possible, check my answer.

Comment: @hungerstar, it doesn't work because of there is no `StdCss-1`, if it is changed to `[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss"][class$="-Cls"]` it will work. Provided it is the only class since the use of `^=` and `$=` in the first and last bracketing. I would probably recommend using `*=` as in the 'purple' example in the answer @temani-afif gave.

Comment: @hungerstar https://jsfiddle.net/gtm0ekph/

Comment: @hungerstar I am not sure what you are trying to proove with your last fiddle. What you mean by *it's only matching on the third part of the selector,*? and why in your fiddle you simply repeated the same selector 3 times?

Comment: @hungerstar there is nothing narcissitic. It's not about being *right* here. It's how CSS selector works. 3 attributes selectors concatenated means an AND condition so the 3 selector need to match in order to select the element and repeating the same selector will make only the last one to be considered (I think you know that). Here is another fiddle that will *probably* convince you https://jsfiddle.net/mw75j14e/2/ . If not, then we can stop here, we aren't obliged to have the same opinion, so need to be rude with each other

Comment: @Temani: "*at some degree it can be possible...*" - yes, but it's an ugly hack at best, horribly fragile *and* verbose. While I would prefer to be able to select elements using attribute-like selectors (begins-with, ends-with, etc) currently it's not reliable without using JavaScript (and there's nothing currently in the [Selectors Level 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#overview) which suggests that's likely to change/improve.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically we can have 4 situations:

Having only the needed class:

```
<div class="Nam-StdCss-*-Cls"></div>
```

Having the needed class at the start

```
<div class="Nam-StdCss-*-Cls ... more-class"></div>
```

Having the needed class at the end

```
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-*-Cls"></div>
```

Having the needed class in the middle

```
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-*-Cls ... more-class"></div>
```

You can write a selector for each one like below:

```css
[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class$="-Cls"]{
  color:red;
}
/*note the space after the class name---------v*/
[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class*="-Cls "]{
  color:blue;
}
/*       v---note the space before the class name*/
[class*=" Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class$="-Cls"]{
  color:green;
}
/*       v------space before and after---------v */
[class*=" Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class*="-Cls "]{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nam-StdCss-Cls">aaa</div>
<div class="Nam-StdCss-anything-Cls">aaa</div>
<div class="Nam-StdCss-Cls ... more-class">bbb</div>
<div class="Nam-StdCss-other-Cls more-class ...">bbb</div>
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-Cls">ccc</div>
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-radius-Cls">ccc</div>
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-Cls ... more-class">ddd</div>
<div class="more-class ... Nam-StdCss-radius-Cls ... more-class">ddd</div>
<br>
<div class="more-class  more-class">not !!</div>
<div class="more-class Nam-StdCss  more-class">not !!</div>
<div class="Nam-StdCss  more-class">not !!</div>
```

You should pay attention as this may target non needed element in some particular cases which is due to the fact that the order doesn't matter for classes.

```css
[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class$="-Cls"]{
  color:red;
}
[class^="Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class*="-Cls "]{
  color:blue;
}
[class*=" Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class$="-Cls"]{
  color:green;
}
[class*=" Nam-"][class*="StdCss-"][class*="-Cls "]{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nam- StdCss- -Cls">aaa</div>

<div class="StdCss- Nam- -Cls">aaa</div>

<div class="-Cls StdCss- Nam-">aaa</div>
```